# How to exclude items have already chosen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on the application which users can choose items but they can't choose ones have already been chosen.

BoardItem has board_id and item_id.
An item that was already chosen should not be included in the selected collection.
Item and board have board items.

```
@board = Board.find(params[:id])
@chosen = BoardItem.select{ |board_item| board_item.board === @board }
@choosing = Item.select{ |item| item.board_items.each do |board_item|
                             @chosen.exclude?(board_item)
                            end }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude selected IDs in the where query as:

```
@board = Board.find(params[:id])
selected_item_ids = @board.board_items.pluck(:item_id)
@unselected_items = Item.where.not(id: selected_item_ids)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it helps me totally :)

Comment: Kudos! I forgot about `@board.board_items` completely and tried executing the same with `Item.joins(:board_items).where('board_items.board_id = ?', @board.id)`.

Comment: A possible suggestion - if relations are set correctly, `@board.item_ids` should give `selected_item_ids`

Comment: yep @kiddorails, but it will fetch `item_ids` through intermediate query of `board_items` which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it with a simple query such as

```
Item.includes(:board).where(boards: {id: nil })
```

You may have to tweak a bit the syntax regarding your models.

The goal is to load all items expect the ones with an existing relation

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate that!